# ActionCable not accessible in coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, actioncable

I am following DHH's tutorial on Rails 5 and action cable, and I've done everything he does.
I have an error in Chrome's console pointing at the file app/assets/javascripts/cable.coffee:

```
#= require cable
#= require_tree ./channels

@App ||= {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

I get `ActionCable is undefined`
I tried to require action_cable instead of cable, and to move the file, but nothing seems to change this. It might be worth noticing that I started with a rails 4 app, and then changed the rails gem to

```
gem 'rails', '5.0.0.beta3'
```

and added:

```
gem 'actioncable', '~> 5.0.0.beta3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need the following as per the docs [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable):

```
# app/assets/javascripts/cable.coffee
#= require action_cable

@App = {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("ws://cable.example.com")
```

Also, it looks like the recommended place to put your Channel files is now `app/assets/javascripts/cable/subscriptions/`.

If that doesn't work, it may not be a bad idea to create a new Rails 5 app and compare initializers and application.coffee to make sure everything is in line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that, and now I get "couldn't find file 'action_cable' with type 'application/javascript'". I did restart my server. I also created a new rails 5 app to compare, but couldn't find the solution

Comment: Try removing `gem 'actioncable', '~> 5.0.0.beta3'` from your Gemfile then `bundle install`. It's not necessary since it's bundled with Rails. You might want to try running `rails app:update` which will give you the option to overwrite or diff the new initializers/config files against your current ones to ensure everything is properly configured. Also, make sure your application.js doesn't have any reference to a file named `action_cable`.